# Update multiple user at the same time in firebase

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have an object in my Firebase 2.x DB which looks similar to this:

```
{
  "users": {
    "$id": {
      "date_of_birth": "June 23, 1912",
      "full_name": "Alan Turing",
      "group": "users",
      "nickname": "Alan The Machine"
    }
  }
}
```

and search for the best way to update multiple users at the same time. For example I want to change all users with the group 'users' into the group 'moderadors' or similar.

How can I do this?

Comment: Of course I can just get all the users with the group X loop through the object and change all group X to group Y and after that write the entire data back via update but I doubt this is the best approach for a db with thousands of users. What I am looking for is basically what I would do in MySQL (update WHERE group = x)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways to approach this and you mention one in your comment.

1) query for all users where group = users. Iterate over each and update the group in each one to group = moderators

2) Add some structure

```
users
  uid_0
    "date_of_birth": "June 23, 1912",
    "full_name": "Alan Turing",
    "group": "-UY89j99j9jasd",
    "nickname": "Alan The Machine"
  uid_1
    "date_of_birth": "June 23, 1912",
    "full_name": "Alan Turing",
    "group": "-Y888jasjdjaos",
    "nickname": "Alan The Machine"
  uid_2
    "date_of_birth": "June 23, 1912",
    "full_name": "Alan Turing",
    "group": "-UY89j99j9jasd",
    "nickname": "Alan The Machine"
```

and the groups

```
-UY89j99j9jasd
  group_name: "users"
-Y888jasjdjaos
  group_name: "dudes"
```

then to turn all current users who are 'users' into moderators, change the group_name to 'moderators'. This is also nice because if you decide that you don't like the word 'moderators' but instead want to call them 'people who pwn' you can do that with one change.

```
-UY89j99j9jasd
  group_name: "moderators"   //or 'people who pwn'
-Y888jasjdjaos
  group_name: "dudes"
```

3) flip your logic and store the users in a moderator or users node.

```
users
  uid_0
    "date_of_birth": "June 23, 1912",
    "full_name": "Alan Turing",
    "nickname": "Alan The Machine"
  uid_1
    "date_of_birth": "June 23, 1912",
    "full_name": "Alan Turing",
    "nickname": "Alan The Machine"
  uid_2
    "date_of_birth": "June 23, 1912",
    "full_name": "Alan Turing",
    "nickname": "Alan The Machine"
```

and the groups

```
-U8asdjoasjds
  group_name: "moderators"
  members:
    uid_0: true
    uid_2: true
-Yuiis9isisis
  group_name: "users"
  members
    uid_1: true
```

Now you can easily get all of the children in the users/members group and add them to the moderators group, and you can also change names of the groups as well.

4) The not recommended way

```
administrators
  uid_0: true
  uid_2: true
users
  uid_1: true
```

this is similar to #3 but the key's identify the group type. Same deal as 3, get the children of users and write them to administrators. It's usually best practice to disassociate key names from the data they contain but it may be ok in this case.

Comment: Thank you Jay, you got some great points here and you explained all wonderful easy to understand. I have basically the situation 2 already but in this case I cant just rename the group have several groups with different permissions and if I delete one group I need to move all users from this group into another one but cant just rename the old group because than I would have maybe double groups. So I will opt for a mix of 1 and 2 in the end. You confirmed my thoughts. I hoped there was some simple easy MySQL type or approach :) but I am happy either way.